# How to prevent listview items checkbox to be de-selected clicking out of checkboxes?

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, checkbox

I've been messing around with checkboxes and listview in my wpf application. Selecting multiple items seems to work properly, but when I click on an item and not on its checkbox it selects the item and deselects all the others previously selected, how can I fix this ?
Here's my code:

```xml
<ListView Name="NewPlace_ActionsList" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="254" Margin="10,74,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="389" >
        <ListView.View> 
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <CheckBox Tag="{Binding Id}" IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ListViewItem}}, Path=IsSelected}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Codice" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Id}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Nome" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Name}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Descrizione" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Desc}" />
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you want to accomplish? The system behaves exactly to what you coded: the checkbox is selected only in the selected row. Because the Checkbox "follows" the IsSelected of the row (ListViewItem).

Comment: The problem, as I said in my post, is that previously selected items get deselected if I click on another item, but not on its checkbox. I would like to have items not deselecting when clicking on some other item, and deselecting singularly only if clicking on the same item or on its selected checkbox.

Comment: Did you try `SelectionMode="Multiple"?

Comment: That did the trick, thanks! I don't know why I was thinking it was something checkbox related.